# C# GroupBy passing value to Key but not including it in GroupBy logic

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to do a GroupBy one on value and pass another value through to be used in the Key, If I have

```
class foo {
    public locationID { get; set; }
    public roleID { get; set; }
}
```

And I do something that returns a list of foo.

```
fooList.GroupBy(g => new { LocationID = g.locationID }).ToList();
```

Above will GroupBy and place LocationID into the Key of the new list.

```
fooList.GroupBy(g => new { LocationID = g.locationID, RoleID = g.roleID }).ToList();
```

Above works as far as putting RoleId into the Key, but then GroupBy uses LocationID & RoleID to do the logical part of the Group By.

What if I want to only group by LocationId but place additional data, RoleID into the Key?  And I do not want to include RoleId in the GroupBy logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group can only have one key. If the elements in each group have different `roleID` values, that would need more than a single `roleID` to hold in the key. If the elements in each group all have the same `roleID` value, grouping by that as well does nothing and is harmless.

Comment: You are right, the more I thought about it, my question doesn't really make sense.  If they are a 1 to 1 relationship then grouping works.  Otherwise using the values in the results works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the `key` and add an additional data, you can *project* your `GroupBy` results to an anonymous type where you could append `roleID` from the first element of your group like:

```
var query = fooList.GroupBy(r => r.locationID)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Key = grp.Key + grp.First().roleID
    });
```

Or you can do:

```
var query = fooList.GroupBy(r => r.locationID)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Key = grp.Key, 
        RoleId = grp.First().roleID,
    });
```

and later you can use:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, RoleID: {1}", item.Key, item.RoleId);
}
```